# Creating unique Table to display different values from 3 other tables

Tags: sql, ssms

I need to list authors first name, last name, and total quantity of their books that have sold. So virtually I need to connect au_id to title_id then connect the SUM(qty) of the sales that correspond with the books they have written.

Do I need to Inner Join? I feel like this is where I'm getting my errors.
Thanks

Tables:
AUTHORS TABLE

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| au_id | au_fname | au_lname |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

TITLEAUTHORS TABLE

```
 +-------+---------
    | au_id |title_id|
    +-------+---------
```

SALES TABLE

```
 +-------+---------
    | title_id | QTY |
    +-------+---------
```

Query:

```
SELECT au_fname, au_lname, TOT FROM(
SELECT au_fname, au_lname FROM authors 
INNER JOIN titleauthors ON authors.au_id = titleauthors.au_id
INNER JOIN sales on titleauthors.title_id = sales.title_id WHERE titleauthors.title_id IN(
SELECT sales.title_id, SUM(sales.qty) TOT from sales
group by sales.title_id)) as t
```

Error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Invalid column name 'TOT'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know,

join statement can't be after another join statement.

And you can't pull out TOT like that.

---

Here is the query for you.

```
SELECT  A.*, TS.title_id, TS.TOT
FROM    AUTHORS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  T.*, S.TOT
    FROM    TITLEAUTHORS T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT   title_id, SUM( QTY ) TOT
        FROM     SALES
        GROUP BY title_id
    ) S
    ON T.title_id = S.title_id
) TS
ON A.au_id = TS.au_id
```

This will work.

Because it has outer join,

TOT can be null. You can solve that by using IF or something according to your database.

---

**EDIT**

If what you wanna do is total sum of sales for each authors regardless of what the title_id is,

then that query should be changed.

```
SELECT  A.au_fname, A.au_lname, SUM( TOT ) TOT
FROM    (
    SELECT  A.*, TS.title_id, TS.TOT
    FROM    AUTHORS A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  T.*, S.TOT
        FROM    TITLEAUTHORS T
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT   title_id, SUM( QTY ) TOT
            FROM     SALES
            GROUP BY title_id
        ) S
        ON T.title_id = S.title_id
    ) TS
    ON A.au_id = TS.au_id
) A
GROUP BY au_id
```

Try this.

And let me know if it goes wrong with this query.

Comment: Awesome that seemed to work! I just need to only show the au_fname, au_lname and the qty! So SELECT A.AU_FNAME, A.AU_lname, TS.tot??

Comment: Also why do some authors have multiple sum columns?

Comment: 1. Yes. A.au_fname, A.au_lname, TS.TOT

Comment: 2. It's possible what you said when there are duplicated records in AUTHORS OR TITLEAUTHORS.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of that should I use select distinct on all of the select statements?